Is it possible to have arrays of mixed C++ templates with known identical SizeOf?
As an example, I have a slab of code something like this:
template <typename T, typename MyTIO>
struct Ticklite
{
    using Ticklite_Impl = T;
    using Impl_InOut = MyTIO;
    TickliteCadence Cadence = TickliteCadence::Lite;
    TicklitePhase RunGroup = TicklitePhase::Normal;
    void* Core;
    void* MemoryBlock;
    TickliteLifecycles Life = TickliteLifecycles::Dropdead;
    uint64_t MadeStamp = 0;
    void CalculateTickable()
    {
        static_cast<Impl_InOut*>(MemoryBlock)->Reset();
        static_cast<Impl_InOut*>(MemoryBlock) = static_cast<Ticklite_Impl*>(Core)->Calculate();
    }
    void ApplyTickable()
    {
        static_cast<Ticklite_Impl*>(Core)->Apply(
        static_cast<Impl_InOut*>(MemoryBlock)
        );
    }
    void ReturnToPool()
    {
        static_cast<Ticklite_Impl*>(Core)->Reset();
        static_cast<Impl_InOut*>(MemoryBlock)->Reset();
    }
    ~Ticklite()
    {
        delete static_cast<Ticklite_Impl*>(Core);
        delete static_cast<Ticklite_Impl*>(MemoryBlock);
    }
};

This is a pretty common pattern, and normally, we'd just drop the type information and store it as a block of memory. I'd really like to avoid doing that. As is, I wouldn't expect this class to generate a vtable, but I could be wrong, so I suspect what I want to do is impossible, but it'd be very nice to avoid needing to use a pure virtual or partial virtual parent class here. Before I swap over to a more standard practice, I figured I'd ask if there was a good way to create, for example, a set<ticklite&> or similar.
So far, I've tried a few variations, including saving a typed pointer then storing the memory elsewhere. This, of course, didn't really work as there's no actual concept of types at runtime in C++ without a vtable, and one goal of templating is to allow you to dodge that as well as dodge the truly awful syntax you get without interfaces and generics.
Normally, I'd just bite the bullet and split out my arrays, or make a base class with virtual methods, but it struck me that this seemed like a pretty common usage. I've tried a few tricks like using pointers or references for incomplete types, but I either mucked up the syntax, or as I remember, that remains impossible with good reason (normally, we cannot guarantee that SizeOf doesn't change when templated).

Do you want T* Core; MyTIO* MemoryBlock;?

What about std::variant? Pointing to a class which can handle such blocks? Comes without virtual functions and use the same memory as it is a tagged union...

@Klaus Oh, variant might be the play here. nice catch! I make a lot of use of optional, but I don't use variant much.

@Jarod42 : Yes, in actual practice. The current code is only to remove as much type info as possible externally, just for the sake of clarifying the question. I don't need anything to be able to reference the types EXCEPT the functions.

Can you show how you want to use it? It seems you want some type erasure, but unclear at which "level", you have Ticklite<T, MyTio> with know types, but with some try to type-erase with void*...

void CalculateTickable()
{
    static_cast<Impl_InOut*>(MemoryBlock)->Reset();
    static_cast<Impl_InOut*>(MemoryBlock) = static_cast<Ticklite_Impl*>(Core)->Calculate();
}
void ApplyTickable()
{
    static_cast<Ticklite_Impl*>(Core)->Apply(
    static_cast<Impl_InOut*>(MemoryBlock)
    );
}
void ReturnToPool()
{
    static_cast<Ticklite_Impl*>(Core)->Reset();
    static_cast<Impl_InOut*>(MemoryBlock)->Reset();
}
~Ticklite()
{
    delete static_cast<Ticklite_Impl*>(Core);
    delete static_cast<Ticklite_Impl*>(MemoryBlock);
}

these methods do different things based on the template parameters.  The difference could be basically arbitrary.  One call to void ReturnToPool() could free memory, another could render a 3d animation of star was in ascii.

This is a pretty common pattern, and normally, we'd just drop the type information and store it as a block of memory. I'd really like to avoid doing that. As is, I wouldn't expect this class to generate a vtable, but I could be wrong, so I suspect what I want to do is impossible, but it'd be very nice to avoid needing to use a pure virtual or partial virtual parent class here.

if you have a bunch of blocks of memory, each holding a template <typename T, typename MyTIO> struct Ticklite of some kind, what could should run if you take block 2112 and invoke CalculateTickable?
To do this, some logic or state or code somewhere has to know the type of block 2112 well enough to run the RIGHT function CalculateTickable.
One approach is to store a pointer to a table in the first bytes of your memory block.  This pointer is to an array of function (well, method) pointers.  When you invoke some_obj.CalculateTickable(), it follows the pointer at the start of some_obj to the table, grabs the first entry, treats it as type void ::*() (member function to a zero-argument void returning function), then invokes it on your some_obj as its (implicit) this parameter.
If you call ApplyTickable, it instead grabs the 2nd entry in this method table.
The name of the method table is a "virtual function table", and the pointer to it is the vtable pointer.
Now, there are many other approaches to this problem.  You could store a function pointer for each of these methods within the Ticklite structure at a known offset, then invoke that.  You could store type information about entries in the array not in the elements of the array - so you'll know from external data that element 2112 is a  specific type (maybe ... every even entry over 2000 is a specific type), and produce the ApplyTickable code to run based on that.
But something has to know.
One trick I use is I create a manual vtable full of function pointers.
struct foo_vtable;
template<class T>
struct tag_t {};
struct foo {
  foo_vtable const* table = 0;
  void print_it(void const* data)const;
  void shake_it(void* data)const;
  template<class T>
  foo create( tag_t<T> );
};

struct foo_vtable {
  void(*printer)(void const*) = 0;
  void(*shaker)(void*) = 0;
};

template<class T>
void shake(T const& x) {
  x = (x<<16)|(x>>16);
}

template<class T>
foo_vtable make_foo_vtable_for() {
  return {[](void const* ptr) {
    std::cout << *static_cast<T const*>(ptr) << "\n";;
  }, [](void* ptr) {
    shake( *static_cast<T*>(ptr) );
  }
}
template<class T>
foo_vtable const* get_foo_vtable() {
  static auto table = make_foo_vtable_for<T>();
  return &table;
}

void foo::print_it(void const* data)const
{
  table->print_it(data);
}
void foo::shake_it(void* data)const {
  table->shake_it(data);
}
template<class T>
foo foo::create( tag_t<T> ) {
  return {get_foo_vtable<T>()};
}

now our foo is polymorphic.

I'm aware of how vtables work and that polymorphism is probably the best option. I don't mind your approach overall, but I would be more likely to simply allow a traditional vtable to be generated by using a polymorphic base class into a template.
regarding the question of arbitrary execution: yes, that's true. under the hood, templates are expanded to full classes, of course, after a fashion, so the type information is actually present at compile, the interface is guaranteed, and the size of the underlying memory is fixed. As a result, all that's missing is type information at run time.

This is just aksing for trouble : static_cast<Impl_InOut*>(MemoryBlock) this is only valid if there is an object there of which the lifecycle has begun.  E.g. you have use placement new, or called something like std::start_lifetime_as

@JakeKurzer yes, you need the type information at run time?  Hence, a pointer to a table of functions or something mathematically equivalent.  There is a huge design space here: in C++ it is called "type erasure".

I'm aware of type erasure.

@JakeKurzer That doesn't clarify anything.  Because your question is "how can I (solve a problem whose solution, in C++ terms, is called) type erasure", yet here you state "I am aware of type erasure", and ... you didn't use the term.  And you talk about virtual function tables as being different than interfaces.  And then complain about generics.  And have a container of references... I suspect you are used to Java or C#, and are using the term "type erasure" as it is used in those languages, which is not quite the same as how C++ uses the term.
